# accessing map value by namespaced keyword

Tags: clojure, hugsql

given a map in clojure, `{::my-func {:meta {...}, :fn #function[hugsql.core/db-fn*]}`, automagically defined, how do I retrieve :fn value?

I've tried

```
(get-in map [:my-func :fn])
(get-in map [::my-func :fn])
(get-in map [:current-namespace/my-func :fn])
(get-in map [:namespaces-it-could-be/my-func :fn])
```

this is in context of hugsql/map-of-db-fns and hugsql/def-db-fns.

Comment: Why does that print as `::my-func`? Who created that keyword, could it be invalid?  E.g. have you tried `(keyword ":my-func")`?

Comment: damn! ... thank you @cfrick, it was due namespace being, indirectly, wrongly defined.

Answer (score 3):

`::x` is a short-cut for writing a namespaced keyword for the *current*
ns.

```
user=> ::x 
:user/x
```

So this is a convenience for the writer of the source or in the REPL,
but does not actually get printed.  Neither directly as seen above or
inside maps

```
user=> {::x 1}
#:user{:x 1}
user=> {::x 1 :y 2}
{:user/x 1, :y 2}
```

So it's to be expected that something went wrong here at some point and
the printed `::my-func` is actually the keyword.  Clojure does not allow
such a keyword, but the function to create them happily accepts any
nonsense.

```
user=> (keyword ":my-func")
::my-func
user=> {(keyword ":my-func") 42}
{::my-func 42}
user=> (let [dont (keyword ":my-func") m {dont 42}] (get m dont))
42
```

Rule of thumb: don't keywordize things, you don't have in your own
hands.  It's just as easy to use string keys for things others have
defined for you. There is way more danger in invalid keywords, that
change the meaning (like `:bro ken`, `::bork`, `:bork,bork`), than to
just use strings.